# How to set default user for guest users in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to create some user which will automatically included if user is not authenticated? For example, if I call `$request->user()` in controller I will get `NULL`. I want to get some default user model in this case (maybe instance of App\User with id == 0). I need it because I want to attach some roles and permissions to guest users via [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a simple middleware that would authenticate users as **Guest** user if they aren't authenticated. The code below should do the trick:

```
class LoginAsGuest {
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if (!Auth::id()) {
      Auth::loginUsingId($guestUserId);
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure this middleware runs last so that user has a chance to be authenticated using their session/cookie data.

Comment: Worth noting that the $next closure also needs to be called